# Difference between ntsysv and system-config-services

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, redhat-enterprise-linux

Please someone can guide the difference between:

```
# ntsysv
# system-config-services
```

**ntsysv** -  tune services should be automatically started, is it similar to chkconfig?